# MiniMax algorithm breaks at any depth greater than two

Tags: c#, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

I'm trying to implement a chessbot and i've been struggling with the following MiniMax function:

```cs
int MiniMax(Board board, int depth, bool maximizingPlayer, int alpha, int beta) {

            if (depth == 0 || IsTerminalState(board))
                return Evaluate(board);
                
            Move[] allMoves = board.GetLegalMoves();

            if (maximizingPlayer) {
                int maxEval = int.MinValue;
                foreach (Move move in allMoves) {
                    board.MakeMove(move);
                    int eval = MiniMax(board, depth - 1, false, alpha, beta);
                    board.UndoMove(move);
                    if(eval > beta) {
                        break;
                    }
                    alpha = Math.Max(eval, alpha);
                    if (eval >= maxEval) {
                        maxEval = eval;
                        bestMove = move;
                    }
                }
                return maxEval;
            }
            else {
                int minEval = int.MaxValue;
                foreach (Move move in allMoves) {
                    board.MakeMove(move);
                    minEval = Math.Min(minEval, MiniMax(board, depth - 1, true, alpha, beta));
                    board.UndoMove(move);
                    if(minEval < alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                    beta = Math.Min(beta, minEval);
                }
                return minEval;
            }
        }
```

If i try to call the function with a depth of 3 or more, as in

`MiniMax(board, 3, true, int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);`

The best move global variable (initialized as a dummy null move) is sometimes a non legal move from that position. That makes me suspect that the way the moves are undone is the cause of my issue.
The function board.UndoMove() undoes a move that was made with the MakeMove method. Moves must be undone in reverse order, so for example, if moves A, B, C are made, they must be undone in the order C, B, A.

Comment: I don't think there's enough context here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: What kind of information do you think would be necessary?

Comment: The rest of the code, basically.

Comment: I'm basing my work on a chess api, so all the function called within the minimax algorithm are not the cause of the problem. The only other function I wrote myself is the evaluation function: it's very barebone and just returns an integer based on the pieces still left on the board

Comment: You should only be able to set `bestMove` at the top level.  Write a separate function for the top level that plays the maximizing player and returns `bestMove`, instead of using a global.  It only needs the `board` and `depth` parameters, and doesn't need to return the score.

Comment: You shouldn't use a global variable for the best move. That obviously gets overwritten with a best move that is valid at a deeper depth, but is not valid for the toplevel call, and if it would be valid, it is not guaranteed to be the best either.